# how to set png image color in winjs

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

Hi I am working on a window 8 app with the help of html and javascript. Where I have to show some png images received from a api and have to set their color as received from the api. I have googled a lot but did not find a solution. Although I know in xaml it can be done some how like this

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=widget.logo, Converter={StaticResource PSWidgetLogoColorConverter1}}" Height="60" Width="60">
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=widget.logo,Converter={StaticResource PSWidgetImageConverter1}}"/>
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
```

but can't figure out how to do it here.

Your valuable suggestions are welcome pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change the color inside a `canvas` element.

1. add the canvas tag to your app:

   ```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" />
   ```
2. load the image inside the canvas:

   ```
   var myImage = new Image();
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

   if (canvas.getContext) {
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     myImage.onload = function() {
       ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
     }
     myImage.src = "kestral.png";
   }
   ```
3. get the image data and change it for your needs:

`getImageData` returns all rgba values inside the canvas at position x,y,width and height. So it is: `getImageData(x,y,width,height)`. As a result you get a Array with the size: width*height*4 You can then loop over it and change every rgba color:

```
    myImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
    var picLength = 200*200;

    // Loop through data.
    for (var i = 0; i < picLength * 4; i += 4) {
      // First bytes are red bytes.        
      // Second bytes are green bytes.
      // Third bytes are blue bytes.
      // Fourth bytes are alpha bytes
      //check for full alpha
      if(myImage.data[i+3] == 255) {
         //change it to black
         myImage.data[i]=0;
         myImage.data[i+1]=0;
         myImage.data[i+2]=0;
         myImage.data[i+3]=0;
      }
    }
```

1. put the changed image data back

   ```
   ctx.putImageData(myImage, 0, 0);
   ```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a good and complete example on msdn.

Comment: Thanks Jan It worked for me but it is displaying a single color blue. In the png image I have tried to change the value in the function ctx.getImageData(0,200,0,200); to get green color but it don't work. I have changed the values for RGB format but it is not displaying the image. Can you figure out what exactly the mistake I am doing.

Comment: getImageData doesn't return a specific rgba. It returns all rgba values inside the canvas at position x,y and width,height. So it is: getImageData(x,y,width,height). As a result you get a Array with the size: width*height*4 You can then loop over it and change every rgba color like I have shown above.